# restrict value of variable, micropython

Tags: python, list, variables, micropython

I'm currently trying to learn `micropython` on the side. Me running into my first problem was that I didn't know how to restrict the value of a variable `c` (should be `[0;11]`)
Now it always activates the `leds` `-2`, `-1` and `12`. How can i restrict it to only activate leds `0-11`?

```
import leds
import utime
import color
red=color.Color(255,0, 0)
green=color.Color(0, 255, 0)
blue=color.Color(0, 0, 255)
toright=True
a=0
b=0
c=0
while True:
    leds.set(a, red)
    leds.set(b, green)
    leds.set(c, blue)
    utime.sleep_ms(100)
    leds.clear()
    if toright==True:
        a=a+1
        b=a-1
        c=a-2
    else:
        a=a-1
        b=a+1
        c=a+2
    if a==10:
        toright=False
    if a==0:
        toright=True
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: putting the c value into a list, but obviously i got the error when it came to led 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to keep a number within a specified range is to use the [modulo](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) operator. It returns the division remainder. Here's an example to keep a number within range 12:

```
>>> 13 % 12
1
>>> 5 % 12
5
>>> -2 %12
10
>>>
```

So for your example you can add the line at the top of your while loop

```
c %=  12
```

To coerce the value of `c` to be in the range of 0-11